# Solve Non Linear Equations Numerically - Python

Tags: python, numpy, sympy

I am looking to reproduce results from a research article.

I am at a point, where I have to find the maximum value of the following equation (w), and corresponding independent variable value (k). k is my only variable.

```
from sympy import *
import numpy as np
import math

rho_l = 1352;
rho_g= 1.225;
sigma = 0.029;
nu = 0.02;
Q = rho_g/ rho_l;
u = 99.67;
h = 1.6e-5; # Half sheet thickness

k = Symbol('k', real=True)
t = tanh(k*h);
w1 = -2 * nu * k**2 * t ;
w2 = 4* nu**2 * k**4 * t**2;
w3 = - Q**2 * u**2 * k**2;
w4 = -(t + Q)
w5 = (- Q* u**2 * k**2  +  (sigma*k**3/ rho_l));
w6 = -w4;

w = ( w1 + sqrt(w2 + w3 + w4*w5))/w6;
```

I was able to solve this using Sympy - diff & solve functions, only when I give t = 1 or a any constant.

Do anyone have suggestions on finding the maximum value of this function? Numerically also works - however, I am not sure about the initial guess value. Good thing is I only have one independent variable.

Edit:

As per the answers given here regarding gradient descent, and also plotting and seeing the maximum value. I literally copied the code lines, that include plotting and I got a different plot.
[image: Plot of w vs k]

Any thoughts on why this is happening? I am using Python 3.7

Comment: You might look into: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html

Answer (score 2):

There are a bunch of ways to do this.  `scipy` in particular has a bunch of optimization algorithms.  I'm going to use gradient descent (or, perhaps more appropriately, gradient *ascent*) and `autograd` because it might be fun.

First, let's import `autograd` and turn your function into a callable function.

```
import autograd.numpy as anp
from autograd import grad
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def w(k):
    rho_l = 1352;
    rho_g= 1.225;
    sigma = 0.029;
    nu = 0.02;
    Q = rho_g/ rho_l;
    u = 99.67;
    h = 1.6e-5; # Half sheet thickness
    t = anp.tanh(k*h);
    w1 = -2 * nu * k**2 * t ;
    w2 = 4* nu**2 * k**4 * t**2;
    w3 = - Q**2 * u**2 * k**2;
    w4 = -(t + Q)
    w5 = (- Q* u**2 * k**2  +  (sigma*k**3/ rho_l));
    w6 = -w4;

    w = ( w1 + anp.sqrt(w2 + w3 + w4*w5))/w6;

    return w
```

Now, we can use `autograd` to compute the gradient of `w` with respect to `k`.  You can add some logic to ensure that the procedure will terminate once we meet some tolerance threshold.

```
dwdk = grad(w)

#Do gradient descent

k = 10.0 #An initial guess
learning_rate = 1
for i in range(1000):

    k+=learning_rate*dwdk(k)
```

And now, let's plot the result to ensure we found the maximum

```
K = np.arange(0,1000)
plt.plot(K,w(K))
plt.scatter(k, w(k), color = 'red')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Please check my question edit. I got a different graph, than you did.

Comment: @JeshKundem There seems to be a problem with however you have implemented the code to make that plot. I'm having no troubles recreating my example, even after copy and pasting your code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another method.  It is an implementation of the Metropolis algorithm, a so-called Markov Chain Monte Carlo method.  Using the definition of `w`, it is possible to construct a Markov Chain of `w(k)` called `wlist`.  The tail of this chain should be the maximum of `w`, and we can recover `k` that got it by storing the `k` values in a list called `kvalues`.

```py
import math
import random

klist = [1.0]
wlist = [w(1.0)] # initialize the chain

# you can tune the value passed to `range`
for _ in range(5000):

    k = random.gauss(klist[-1], 0.2*klist[-1]) # q

    if k <= 0.0: # assuming max has positive `k` arg
        continue

    w_hat = w(k)

    if w_hat > wlist[-1]:
        klist.append(k)
        wlist.append(w_hat)

    else:
        u = random.random()
        try:
            alpha = math.exp(-w_hat) / math.exp(-wlist[-1])
        except ZeroDivisionError:
            alpha = 1.0
        if u >= alpha:
            klist.append(k)
            wlist.append(w_hat)
        else:
            klist.append(klist[-1])
            wlist.append(wlist[-1])

wlist[-10:], klist[-10:]
```

Which should return approximately (my seed is not set) something like this:

```py
([8679.594992731532,
  8679.594992731532,
  8679.594992731532,
  8679.594992731532,
  8679.594992731532,
  8679.594992731532,
  8679.594992731532,
  8679.594992731532,
  8679.594992731532,
  8679.594992731532],
 [416.22335719432436,
  416.22335719432436,
  416.22335719432436,
  416.22335719432436,
  416.22335719432436,
  416.22335719432436,
  416.22335719432436,
  416.22335719432436,
  416.22335719432436,
  416.22335719432436])
```

Answer (score 0):

My thought is that the function returning values for w (your blue line) might be a truncated estimate (with a polynomial maybe)? Is the formula for w off by a factor of 10 or so?

Comment: May be. But I literally copied Dimitri's code. However, if I do your code, I am getting the right curve

Comment: I see. The think Demetri’s definition of `w` is actually the `autograd` of `w`

Answer (score -1):

I do not expect that there is an analytical solution to this problem. There is a theory of pfaffian functions for which it is possible to provide certificate that there are no roots for given range. See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pfaffian_function.
However this heavy artilery.

If you are not sure about initial guess try to compute the function for a large number of random points (e.g.million) and select the best one as starting point. This approach works really well for low dimensional, differentiable problems